# What does $\mathrm{codim} V \ll_\delta 1$ mean if codimension can only be $0$ or $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I am trying to read [arXiv:1510.08739](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.08739) on "Fourier Uniformity".  Here is the abstract:

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a fixed finite field, and let $A \subset \mathbb{F}^n$. It is a well-known fact that there is a subspace $V \leq \mathbb{F}^n$, $\boxed{\color{#97C757}{\mathbf{\mbox{codim} V \ll_{\delta} 1}}}$, and an $x$, such that $A$ is $\delta$-uniform when restricted to $x + V$ (that is, all non-trivial Fourier coefficients of $A$ restricted to $x + V$ have magnitude at most $\delta$). We show that if $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{F}_2$ then it is possible to take $x = 0$; that is, $A$ is $\delta$-uniform on a subspace $V \leq \mathbb{F}^n$. We give an example to show that this is not necessarily possible when $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{F}_3$.

Basically, any subset of $A \subset \mathbb{F}^n$ has some slide that is almost "uniform" (maybe like "[equidistributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence)") to within descrepancy $\delta$.

What does $\mathrm{codim}V \ll_\delta 1$ mean, here?  Hopefully any [hyperplane](http://web.mit.edu/6.034/wwwbob/svm-notes-long-08.pdf) has codimension = 1.

[image]

What does it mean to have co-dimension $\ll 1$ ?  Basically there is co-dimension **1** and co-dimension **0**.  Can it be $\mathrm{codim} < 1 - \delta^2 $ ?  That is absurd.  And I definitely have no idea what co-dimension $\ll_\delta 1$ means with the parameter, $\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually $ x \ll 1$ does not mean $x < 1$.  In fact, $100 \ll 1$ since we can find a constant so that $100 < C \times 1$.  In fact

$$ 100 < 101 \times 1 $$

Your co-dimension could be 2 or more.  For example the line $(0,0,1)\cdot \mathbb{F} \subset \mathbb{F}^3$ has co-dimension 2 and yet is perfectly uniform along itself.

[image]
[image]

Here is a sample plot of the co-dimension against the tolerance $\delta$.  If we tolerate less, then ultimately we need 0 codimension.